# Рекурсивное сохранение TreeView в XML

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, treeview

Есть код с рекурсией внутри, проблема в том что вываливается переполнение стека, с тем учетом что условие выхода из рекурсивного перехода предусмотрел, возможно оно не правильное?

```
   //Метод сохранения TreeView в XML
    //current - текущий элемент XML 
    //item - текущий элемент TreeView
    private void SaveTreeItems(XElement current, TreeViewItem item)
    {
        foreach (TreeViewItem tree_item in item.Items)
        {
            Border b = tree_item.Header as Border;

            StackPanel stk = b.Child as StackPanel;

            Border port_in_border = stk.Children[0] as Border;

            TextBlock port_in = port_in_border.Child as TextBlock;

            Border port_out_border = stk.Children[1] as Border;

            TextBlock port_out = port_in_border.Child as TextBlock;

            TextBlock address = stk.Children[2] as TextBlock;

            TextBlock ip = stk.Children[3] as TextBlock;


            string _ip = ip.Text;

            string _address = address.Text;

            string _port_in = port_in.Text;

            string _port_out = port_out.Text;


            XElement newNode = new XElement(_address,
                                            new XAttribute("IP", _ip),
                                            new XAttribute("port_in", _port_in),
                                            new XAttribute("port_out", _port_out));
            //Возможно здесь неправильное условие выхода из рекурсии
            if (item.HasItems)
            {
                SaveTreeItems(newNode, item);
            }

            current.Add(newNode);
        }

    }

    private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeViewItem root = DeviceTree.Items[0] as TreeViewItem;

        XElement root_ = new XElement(root.Header.ToString());

        XDocument xdoc = new XDocument(root_);

        TreeViewItem tw = DeviceTree.Items[0] as TreeViewItem;

        SaveTreeItems(root_, tw);

        xdoc.Save("device.xml");
    }
```

Comment: Возможно , но вы уверены, что здесь вообще нужна такая рекурсия?

Comment: @FoggyFinder возможно и можно, но я не до конца пойму как написать итеративно. Это намного больше кода будет и сложнее

Comment: можно попробовать использовать `XmlWriter` вместо `Linq2XML`

Comment: условие выхода да, неправильное итерации просто не будет если коллекция будет пустая

Comment: насколько большое у вас дерево?

Comment: А в чем вообще идея сохранять `TreeView` в XML, какую цель вы преследуете?

Comment: @sp7 хороший вопрос =)

Comment: @sp7 что бы другие программы дергали в древовидной XML нужную ветвь и работали с ней

Comment: @FoggyFinder около 500-800 узлов будет. А как можно сделать условие что бы алгоритм не падал в переполнение стека?

Comment: @ГеоргийЖиленко что значит `что бы другие программы дергали в древовидной XML нужную ветвь`?

Comment: @sp7 а значит то что б другие программы не перебирали весь список в поисках целевого устройства и его дочерних элементов, а могли сразу работать с определенной ветвью, у меня другие программы постоянно будут обращаться к этой XML и в целях времени и экономии ресурсов было принято решение делать XML деревом

Comment: @FoggyFinder а как тогда лучше с xmlwriter сохранить?

Comment: @ГеоргийЖиленко как-то у вас все сложно получается. Ка вы потом будете подсовывать другой программе нужную ветвь, кто ее будет искать?

Comment: @sp7 Ну типа того: другая программа получила МАК устройства, и глянула в XML, Ага вот и он теперь нужно глянуть весь маршрут от этого элемента и до корня, ага и получилась веточка, которую подхватила другая программа. Это я рассказал принцип работы моего vlan трейсера

Comment: ...вы как данные в `TreeView` загружаете?

Comment: @Ev_Hyper из формы

Comment: есть какие ни будь идеи?

Comment: ...код покажите

Comment: @Ev_Hyper того что в вопросе - мало?

Comment: @FoggyFinder в общем я пришел к выводу что я просто тупой. Я в метод    SaveTreeItems(newNode, item); передаю не конкретный объект из цикла, корневой самый первый

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужно строковое представление вашего `TreeView` используйте класс `System.Windows.Markup.XamlWriter`, для того что бы осуществить обратную операцию, т.е. получить из строки объект используйте `System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader`. В коде это выглядит так:

```
// Получаем строку, которая представляет ваш TreeView.
var str = System.Windows.Markup.XamlWriter.Save(myTree);

// Из строки получаем объект TreeView.
var obj = (TreeView)System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Parse(str);
```

Так как XAML это диалект XML, то при желании из полученной строки мы можем получить `XDocument`.

```
var str = System.Windows.Markup.XamlWriter.Save(myTree);
var doc = XDocument.Parse(str);
```

Comment: у меня в TreeViewItem.Header хранится объект собственно который нужно сохранить, но он запакованный в разные контейнеры, как в листинге выше, мне ничего не остается как обходить все дерево